# put div on top of ace editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, ace-editor

I am using an ace editor instance in my webpage:

```
<div class="tabpage" id="tabscontent">
     <div class="ace_page" id="tabpage_1">
     </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript file initializes this div as an ace editor instance:

```
var aceEditor = ace.edit("tabpage_1");
aceEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/textmate");
aceEditor.getSession().setMode(language);
```

Now I would like to put div in the `tabpage_1` so that this will be on top of the editor instance using this code:

```
function addUserCursor(editor, position, user, color) {
var page = document.getElementById("tabscontent");
var label = document.createElement("div");
label.setAttribute("id", editor+"-"+user);
label.setAttribute("position", "absolute");
label.setAttribute("top", "200px");
label.setAttribute("left", "200px");
label.setAttribute("background-color", color);
label.setAttribute("z-index", "10");
label.innerHTML = user;
page.appendChild(label);
```

}

But this doesn't result in a div that is on top of that editor(the styleattributes will be collected in a css later, this is only for testing). Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What z-index is used for the ace editor?

Comment: I looked at it too, but I didn't find a reason for this: the z-index of "tabpage_1" isn't set explicitly, while the divs that are generated by ace-editor have a maximum z-index of 4 (line numbers div and for the cursorlayer)

Comment: try to put your DIV after the HTML-code of the Editor. The HTML-Code is read sequencely and the latest element, if position:absolute, lays over the element before

Comment: Which position-value has the editor? You choose position:absolute, but what position-value has the editor? Maybe show some more code

Comment: The div (= var label) that has to be on top has indeed position absolute, with coordinates 200px,200px (set in the addUserCursor function). Since this function also append the div to the editor, the HTML code of the div is already at the end of the tabscontent HTMLcode

Answer (score 1):

`label.setAttribute("z-index", "10");` is wrong it must be `label.style.zIndex = 10;`